# Migrate Clash of Clans data from Android to iOS

Tags: data-transfer, ios, google-play-games, clash-of-clans

I have a CoC account on my iPad. I got an Android phone and set up a second account there. Now I got a new iPhone and I want to use my Android CoC account on that, but when I log in my iPhone, it pulls the one I have on iPad.

I have logged out of Game Center but no idea how to move into my Google account on the iPhone to pull that account over.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to link your ios device to android device

Log in to Apple-account/game center on both devices.
After that follow the steps-

1. On android device, go to settings inside Clash of Clans
2. Press "Link a device" on android device
3. Press "This is the old device" on android device
4. On iPhone go to settings inside "Clash of Clans"
5. Press "This is the new device" on iPhone
6. Press "I want to link to another device" on Android (you will see a code)
7. Enter (on iPhone) the code you have on Android.
8. It will ask you if you want to replace the village you have on iPhone with the village you have on Android.
9. Hit "Yes" on iPhone
10. Type in "CONFIRM"
11. Hit enter.
12. It will now load up and you have your village on both devices. Enjoy!
13. Keep in mind you can only have your village open at one device at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to link it to your facebook or google profile. There after you can sign in from any device and still have it sync with your profile.